# NSDate formatting in separated hours and minutes

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsdate

I have a random NSDate it can be 21:55:33 for example.

I just want to parse it to 2 different variable:

1. NSDate that will be 21:00:00 (hours)
2. NSDate 00:55:33 (minutes+seconds)

Comment: What does this have to do with Xcode? What have you tried?

Comment: It is for my sql data base. i need a start time(a hour 21:00) and a duration it is 55:33 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSDateComponents` to extract the hour/minute/second from an `NSDate` object:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit
                                      fromDate:now];
NSInteger hour = [comps hour];
NSInteger minute = [comps minute];
NSInteger second = [comps second];
```

You can then format the time as required using the `hour`/`minute`/`second` values.

Answer (score 0):

trojanfoe's answer is very much satisfied, Still if want to try below approach:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormater=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSString * strDate=[dateFormater stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"HH:00:00"];
NSDate * date1 = [dateFormater dateFromString:strDate];

[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"00:mm:ss"];
NSDate * date2 = [dateFormater dateFromString:strDate];
```